# what is the actual type of streamsize,streamoff and other stream related data type

Tags: c++, stream, fstream

when i want to find out the actual data type of streamsize,the cpp reference says

> Type to represent sizes and character counts in streams.
>
> It is a typedef of one the fundamental signed integral types.
>
> It is convertible to/from streamoff.

It confused me,and the explanations of other types like streamoff,streampos,fpos are similar.

Comment: Is it "signed integral types" that seems to be griefing you?

Comment: This machinery was designed for C++03 and earlier which didn't have any guaranteed 64-bit type, and e.g. a file offset could in practice be larger than the 32-bit limit.

Comment: Yes,i can't figure out what does signed integral types really mean.@WhozCraig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term "integral types" means that they are of "some integer type", but not necessarily `int`. `signed` means they can be take both positive and negative. The reason for having a signed value for the size is that the `streamoff` and type, which can be both forwards (positive) and backwards (negative) in the file - for when you want to re-read something in the file, you seek relative to the current position and a negative offset.

Of course, the size itself will not be negative.

Comment: But which data type will it actually be?And according to what law?@Mats Petersson

Comment: @YuanWen [*a signed integral type **of sufficient size to represent the maximum possible file size supported by the operating system**. Typically, this is a typedef to `long long`.*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/streamoff)

Answer (score 0):

Integral types means they can be int,unsigned int, long, unsigned long and so on.It depends on your machine and compiler.For example,in my machine:win7 64, vs2013 win32 Debug.The output of
`cout << sizeof(streamsize) << endl;
 cout << sizeof(streamoff) << endl;`
 
is 8,8.In other environment,it may be different.